# Distinguish if UIsegmentedontrol value change is from user or from system

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hello I have a UISegmentedControl with two segments. The selected segment is modified programmatically in some case and by the user in some other. I only want to trigger the selector when the change is due to a user action(only when user actually press the segmented control and not when the system do segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = ...). Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
[self.segment setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
```

This will not call the action of valueChanged on the segment, so what is your question?

Comment: no need it happens more than you imagine, i had to test it to make sure :)

Answer (score 1):

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];


- (IBAction)segmentAction:(id)sender {
 // valuechanged connected function

        UISegmentedControl *segControll = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

    if (segControll.tag == 0) {


       }
        else {

            isProgramaticallyChanged = NO; //important

        }



}
```